# ¿Cómo puedo verificar si un atributo tiene ingresada información?

Tags: java

En mi ejercicio tengo creada 3 clases, la principal y las otras dos:

- Personaje

  ```
  //atributos de clase Personaje
  private String tipo;
  private String Nombre;
  private String Lugar_de_Nacimiento;
  private int Edad;
  private double Estatura;
  private double Nivel_de_pelea;
  private transformacion Transformacion; 
  //aquí hago una relación con class transformacion
  ```
- Transformacion.

  ```
  // atributos de clase transformacion:
  private int Codigo;
  private String Nombre;
  private String Cambio_de_Apariencia;
  private int multi_poder;
  ```

En vista de lo anterior, mi problema es cuando creo un método *boolean* dentro de la clase **Personaje**, no sé como verificar, en este caso si tengo o no información ingresada en el atributo **Transformacion** de la clase **Personaje**:

```
public boolean tieneTrasformacion()
{
return true;
return false;
}
```

Comment: Hola, necesitas revisar la lógica de tu programa. En el método tieneTransformacion tienes declarado dos return.

Comment: @FernandoCarraro exacto el return true es para verificar si el atributo transformacion tiene informacion ingresada, caso contrario si no tiene entonces me devuelve false. Esa es la finalidad del metodo "tieneTransformacion"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El método sería simplemente esto, en la clase `Persona`:

```
 public boolean tieneTransformacion(){
     return !(this.transformacion==null);
 }
```

Devolverá `false` cuando la instancia de la clase no tenga `Transformacion` o `true` cuando tenga.

Comment: Me sirvió de mucho. Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Para verificar si un atributo tiene un dato primero hay que asignarlo.

```
Personaje personaje = new Personaje();
personaje.setNombre("Tomas");
personaje.setEdad(32);

if(personaje.getNombre().length() > 0 ){
    System.out.println("Hola "+personaje.getNombre());
}

if(personaje.getEdad() > 0 ){
    System.out.println("Edad mayor a cero");
}
```

También sería recomendable que respetaras el [CamelCase](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase) de Java en los atributos.

No es necesario declarar un método con dos return. Debes respetar la lógica.

```
interface Servicio{
   boolean esVerdadero(String cadena);
}


class ServicioImplA implements Servicio{
  @Override public boolean esVerdadero(String cadena){
        return "Rojo".equals(cadena);
   }

}

//En un método main
ServicioImplA servicioImplA = new ServicioImplA();
String color = "verde";
String resultado = servicioImplA.esVerdadero(color)? "Es rojo" : "Es "+color;
```

Answer (score 0):

otro opción sería de la siguiente forma:

```
 public boolean tieneTrasformacion()
    {
     Optional<Transformacion> optTransformacion = Optional.ofNullable(transformacion);
     return optTransformacion.isPresent();
    }
```

Con el empleo de `Optional` puedes evitar nulos en tu aplicación, con el uso de `isPresent()` valida si el objeto tiene asignada una referencia, por lo tanto retorna **true** en caso contrario **false**.

Comment: por que? recuerda que solo poner código se considera de baja calidad, edita esto y explicalo